# What's the shortest number one chart hit?

Tags: charts, number-ones

In any country, what's the shortest number one chart hit? (Either duration of the 'A-side' / main track, or total duration)

Comment: No 2019 there’s a shorter song called “I suffer more”

Comment: This is not very useful without information on who it's by and in which country.

Comment: also link to song on Yt or similar

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The shortest chart topper for the UK Singles Chart is Adam Faith's "[What Do You Want?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/What_Do_You_Want%3F)", clocking in at 1:38.  It spent three weeks at number 1 beginning the week of [December 4, 1959](http://web.archive.org/web/20090323081036/http://theofficialcharts.com/all_the_no1_songs.php).

In the US, the shortest number 1 on the Billboard Hot 100 chart is "[Stay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stay_%28Maurice_Williams_song%29)" by Maurice Williams and the Zodiacs.  It spent only one week at number 1, on [November 21, 1960](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Billboard_Hot_100_number-one_singles_of_1960).  I've seen various reports on the length of this song ranging from [1:37](http://sponge-headedscienceman.blogspot.com/2010/11/shortest-number-1-hit.html) to [1:50](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stay_%28Maurice_Williams_song%29).